# Adjectives with Latin etymology when noun has non-Latin etymology

Tags: etymology, nouns, adjectives, history, latin

As a non-native English speaker, I always wondered why, for example, you say *moon*, but then you say *lunar* (same goes for *side* and *lateral*, *hand* and *manual* and so forth): in some cases, the noun is not the base of the adjective, which derives from the Latin root instead.

What is the reason for this phenomenon?

Comment: Notice that hardly anyone every forms the adjective form of 'Venus' correctly.

Comment: @Brian Hooper -- "Venusian"?  "Venereal"?  "Aphrodisious"?  I've seen "Jovian" for the moons of Jupiter (though never "Jovial").  If Mercury had a moon, would it be Hermetic?  Poe talks about "the night's Plutonian shore", should he have said "Hadian"?  "Haderific"?

Comment: @Malvolio, Venereal is, I am told, correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's not forget that Latin was the language of science and philosophy and nearly all higher learning for hundreds of years. For example, Copernicus wrote his seminal treatise about the heliocentric theory, *De revolutionibus orbium coelestium*, in Latin. It's not surprising that many of the technical names for natural phenomena and educated words in general would be derived from Latin.

We see remnants of this today in medicine: the parts of the body are named from the Latin. Your orthopedist will tell you you've torn your medial collateral ligament in your knee.

Answer (score 7):

The sort of vocabulary that you would expect the simple folk of the Dark Ages to be using are mostly still of Germanic origin; they are the building blocks of the language, the basics of verb and noun forms, and words for basic abstract concepts.

In later years, the Catholic Church's supremacy meant that the language of inquiry, knowledge, and spirituality was Latin. For many centuries, scientists would publish all their work in Latin. It is no surprise that Latin has filled the gaps in English and provided adjectives such as *lunar* where English had none.

This is compounded by the imposition of Norman French in the Middle Ages. Since the language of government changed from English, many of our words for government and justice derive from Latin via Norman French. Our words for meats also come from Norman French, e.g. *beef, veal, venison, mutton* in place of English *cow, calf, deer, sheep*.

Later still, British scholars would turn to Latin and Greek to coin new words to describe new technologies and modern concepts, as we still do today.

There's an interesting discussion of the influence of Latin on English on wikipedia here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_influence_in_English

Comment: Very interesting answer. Nevertheless, it doesn't fully satisfy me: the concept of 'related to the moon' certainly wasn't unknown to the peasants of the Middle Ages. So, either there wasn't an adjective to describe that concept, or there was one that doesn't come from Latin. Or it was _lunar_, but then the whole explaination of Latin being used for "high" culture seems a bit unsatisfactory :)

Comment: It's not necessarily for 'high' culture. Even today less educated speakers will use a smaller, simpler vocabulary. They wouldn't use *lateral* (because it's not in their personal lexicon) and would improvise a periphrasis. There's no reason to think that mediaeval speakers wouldn't have been the same, maybe referring to *the moon's --* rather than *lunar --*.

Answer (score 3):

The English language is a hotchpotch of many languages, a melting pot from most European language roots, with a good deal of other elements thrown in for added spice.

As a result, we often have a vast array of words to choose from for any given topic of conversation.  The more elemental and eternal the concept, the longer we will have talked about it and thus the further back through our history words will have been borrowed in order to discuss the concepts.

Generally, you will find that the simple forms of words are likely to hark back to older influences; basic words are often from Old English, or Saxon influence.  Whilst more technical terms may not have been so common in the vernacular speech, so may retain scientific form, coming from Latin or Greek.

The essential rule to remember is that English etymology is a many splendored thing; variety is the spice of life, after all.

Comment: Hotchpotch? I think you mean `hodge-podge`. :)

Comment: @Noldorin: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hotchpotch -- *hotchpotch* is older, *hodge-podge* is a more recent alternate.

Comment: Before I even read your comment (@Noldorin), *hodge-podge* instantly sprung to mind on reading the first sentence of this answer!

Comment: @Orbling: Ah alright, Mr. Old Fashioned, you win! ;) I only ever here `hodge-podge` to be fair; it's easily the more *common* form these days, if not the older one.

Comment: @Jimi: Hah, yeah. I thought it had a different meaning at first, but evidently just a variant!

Comment: @Orbling: Just curious, do you actually say *hotchpotch* as well, or do you only spell it that way?!

Comment: @Jimi Oke: I say it that way too I'm afraid, my grandparents always did and I think it stuck.  I could be misremembering, but I think most people I know use that form, rather than `hodge-podge`.

Comment: @Orbling: Wow, cool! Definitely a Britishism, but clearly the original. *Hodge-podge* is certainly better for American English, as it flows with the long *aw* sound!

Comment: @Jimi Oke: Fortunately it is a word that I do not use every single day. ;-)

Comment: @Orbling: Indeed, that may be very fortunate, but, well, since most of the people you know use that form, then it probably isn't too much of an issue. Interestingly, *hotchpot* (similar meaning in law) never changed to *hodgepot* in American. I cannot but think of *hopscotch*, pronounced in a crisp British accent, whenever I see the *hotchpotch* on this page :)

Comment: LOL, well I can probably come up with a "hopscotch of many languages" if the need arises.  Though it may not entirely help the question.

Answer (score 2):

Some [simplistic] reasons:

- The Latin-based adjective is more elegant for contextual reasons, e.g. *sideways* vs. *lateral*
- It is impossible to form an adjective otherwise, e.g. *sun* :: *solar*
- And better a word than a phrase, e.g. *lunar* vs. *of the moon*
- The non-Latin adjective may mean something else entirely, e.g. *handy* vs. *manual*

Comment: how can it be impossible? there must have been a way to express the concept of 'related to the sun' without resorting to Latin in the language(s) English comes from, right?

Comment: I use *impossible* in the sense that an absolute *word* may not be possible without the Latin (or the Greek). Thus, one would have *of the sun*, an adjectival phrase, as in *eclipse of the sun* or compound *sun* with another noun, as in *sundial* or *sun god*. You may be able to better come to terms with my reasons if you view them as direct responses to the specific questions the OP asked, rather than as general rules for any context :)

Comment: I don't think it's impossible to form English adjectives where only latin equivalents exist. It's just that we don't, because we HAVE the latin word. Just as someone coined the word "sunny" we could have "sunnic" or "sunnly" or "sunnal" or something else. But we don't, because everyone knows the word "solar".

Comment: @Mr. Shiny and New: Oh, yeah, I forgot about *sunny*! But *sunny* ≠ *solar* (my fourth reason). Most of the adjectives ending with *-al* are from Latin, while those ending with *-ic* are from Greek or French. It's the Saxon words that usually end with *-y*!

Comment: The adjective *moody* comes from moon, and [moonly](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/moonly), which I find to be rather elegant  is derived from Old English  *mōnelīc*, so  it is perfectly possible to create adjectives from "Saxon" words such as *sun*, *moon* and *hand* e.g. *handling* is still used today.

Answer (score 2):

To emphasize Robusto's point (3). Sir Issac Newton published his Philosophie Naturalis Principia Mathematica not in English but in Latin in 1687. 
This was the last major work written in Latin published in England. However,
the level of Latin at Cambridge and Oxford was and remained quite high. 
Perhaps no more than that of Gottingen or Tubingen in Germany. But "OxBridge" exerted more influence on the Kingdom of England than Gottingen/Tubingen et al exerted on the many German States. 
To the English writer back then (and even till the present) Latin roots seem more fitting for abstract words.

Answer (score 0):

All of these answers are Useful and True. I want only to supplement them with two observations:

- There's a strong 'native' tendency in English to use the bare noun attributively rather than to derive a frank adjective: from your examples, *moon beam*, *side dish*, *hand axe*
- Where we do have adjectives built with ordinary suffixes, they have often evolved specific senses which do not sort comfortably with a simple "of or pertaining to X": again from your list, *moony*, *sideways*, *handy*

So there's a lot more what-you-might-call "lexical space" to put Latinate adjectives into, and often a specific lexical need for them.